Unable to Connect to Remote Desktop on Local Network - Diagnosing with CMD/PowerShell
I've recently encountered an issue with Remote Desktop Connection that stumps me. I have two Windows computers on the same Wi-Fi network. Until recently, I could connect without problems, but now I'm getting the following error:

               

Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:
1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Here's what I've tried so far:
Client Side: (cmd)

Ping Test:
ping 192.168.2.32

Result:
Request timed out.


Port Test: (powershell)
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.2.32 -Port 3389

Result:
WARNING: TCP connect to (192.168.2.32 : 3389) failed
WARNING: Ping to 192.168.2.32 failed with status: TimedOut
TcpTestSucceeded : False



Server Side:

IP Configuration: (cmd)
ipconfig

Result (Wi-Fi adapter details):
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.32
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.254


Remote Desktop Service Status: (PowerShell)
Get-Service -Name TermService

Result:
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  TermService        Remote Desktop Services


Firewall Rule Creation: (PowerShell)
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In)" -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 3389 -Action Allow -Profile Any
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Remote Desktop - User Mode (UDP-In)" -Direction Inbound -Protocol UDP -LocalPort 3389 -Action Allow -Profile Any



Despite this, Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop" returns no results, and the connection tests fail. Here are the full command outputs:
Get-NetFirewallRule : No MSFT_NetFirewallRule objects found with property 'DisplayGroup' equal to 'Remote Desktop'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop" | Where-Object { $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remote Desktop:String) [Get-NetFirewallRule], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_DisplayGroup,Get-NetFirewallRule


What I Need:
I'm seeking help diagnosing and resolving this issue using CMD/batch or PowerShell. What additional diagnostic steps can I take? How can I ensure the Remote Desktop is configured correctly and listening to the correct port?

First, temporarily disable the firewall on the serverside and test if RDP works afterwards. This way, you can narrow down if it is the firewall or not. If it works with the firewall down, look further into how to configure the firewall. Do note, by default, there are already firewall rules for Remote desktop or Terminal Services, that you can enable. If serverside firewall is not the issue, check clientside firewall and check if RDP actually works. Also, consider a reboot of the server at this point. Also, test with paping 192.168.2.32 -p 3389 (third party tool)
